# Write a decrypted file to memory

Tags: java, xml, encryption, cryptography, memory-mapped-files

I have an XML file for storing session records in my Java project. The session records will be encrypted, but at times i will have to decrypt it. I have seen codes regarding encrypting and decrypting files, where the decrypted files are written as plain text file, which can be access or seen by the users. I don't want this to happen, I wish to fetch the encoded data from the encrypted file, decode it and store it in the memory for the later use like parsing the XML file.

Is there any provision in Java to get the data from a `byte[] array` or a `string` and to save it **into memory** and to **read it later** from the memory?

I know this is a dirty way to store data, but is there any other suggestion to encrypt and use the user sessions in an XML or plain text file, like how Google Chrome or Mozilla or other software save their encrypted cache in our computer and fetch it securely? I need something like that! I have no idea how they do that. Kindly assist me regarding this thing.

Note that I do not wish to integrate MySQL with this Java project.

Comment: I'm quite sure you don't want to use memory mapping ( at least regarding memory mapped files) and this question is in no way xml related. Could you explain what is meant by "save into memory"?

Comment: @dirk thanks for your reply. As I said in the question I need to securely save and access user credentials somewhere in my computer. Im thinking of encrypting and saving the data in an XML file and to decrypt it for later use. Others should not see anything written in this cache file. So I thought to decrypt the file contents and save it(user data)  in memory. That's it. Is there any other way to achieve high secrecy for the cached data and to access them without any troubles?

Answer (score 1):

There is absolutely nothing in the Java Cryptography Architecture that even handles files. So it is perfectly possible to use memory instead of files.

It seems you want to encrypts specific parts of the XML file. This means it is probably best to opt for the XML-Enc specification. There are libraries available for Java that implement XML encryption.

You can take a look at my answer to the following question to understand how to enable XML enc for your application.

[Sun provides a Java API to the XML-Enc specification?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5888204/sun-provides-a-java-api-to-the-xml-enc-specification)

Comment: I've skipped answering the last paragraph, as it is both too broad and off topic. You can ask a separate (set) of questions on security.stackexchange.com after checking if no answer already exists.